# differential calculus without the limit notion

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, non trivial ($1\neq 0$) and such that every $n=1+\ldots+1$ ($n$ times, $n\neq 0$) is invertible in $R$ (in other words $R$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$). We suppose $R$ is not a field. Then we define
$$D:=\{h\in R:h^2=0\}$$
$\textbf{AXIOM}$: for every function $f:R\longrightarrow R$, for every $x\in R$, for every $h\in D$, there exists one and only one element $m\in R$, which we denote by $f'(x)$ such that
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+h\cdot f'(x)$$

Now i want to prove the following statement
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}$$
In order to prove this, i take $h,k\in D$ and i use Axiom to write:
$f(x+h,y+k)=f(x,y+k)+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+k)=f(x,y)+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)+h[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+k\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)]=f(x,y)+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+hk\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)$

On the other side, derivating first respect to $y$ and then to $x$ we get:

$f(x+h,y+k)=f(x,y)+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)+kh\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)$

By comparing and simplifying we finally get

$$hk\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=hk\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$$

How can i prove 
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$$
from this?

Comment: Do we need some additional assumptions on $R$? As it stands I can't see why we couldn't have zero divisors, in which case the identity would not necessarily hold.

Comment: Indeed, if $h$, $k \in D$, then $hk = \tfrac{1}{2}((h+k)^2-h^2-k^2) = 0$, so that you can't actually conclude anything from your final computed equality.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong the problem is exactly what you said, $R$ is not a field, not a domain, so we can't divide, but i found this proposition on a book which gives no giustification for the last equation, hence my question here.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić $h,k\in D$ does not imply $h+k\in D$, in general

Comment: Ah! You're absolutely right.

Comment: How about if $h = k$. Then the equation is just $0 = 0$ and you can't deduce anything from it.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong yes, in that case i actually can't. But the equation $hk\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=hk\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$ holds for every choice of $h,k\in D$

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, as you've defined the partial derivative, it is a function of $h$ and $k$.

Comment: Perhaps the axiom should rather read "for every $x$ there exists one and only one element $m$ such that for every $h \in D$"?

Comment: I guess that would resolve some issues, but then this formulation wouldn't exactly agree with the classical sense of differentiation.

Comment: No it wouldn't; I think this approach ultimately comes form synthetic differential geometry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_differential_geometry

Comment: Ah, I see. That is very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand,
$$
f(x+h,y+k) = f(x,y) + k \partial_y f(x,y) + h \partial_x f(x,y) + hk \partial_y\partial_x f(x,y)\\ = f(x+h,y) + k\left(\partial_y f(x,y) + h \partial_y \partial_x f(x,y) \right),
$$
and on the other hand,
$$
f(x+h,y+k) = f(x,y) + h \partial_x f(x,y) + k \partial_y f(x,y) = kh \partial_x \partial_y f(x,y)\\ = f(x+h,y) + k\left(\partial_y f(x,y) + h \partial_x\partial_y f(x,y)\right).
$$
Hence, by the axiom applied to $F(y) = f(x+h,y)$ for fixed $x$ and $h$, 
$$
 \partial_y f(x,y) + h \partial_y \partial_x f(x,y) = \partial_y f(x,y) + h \partial_x\partial_y f(x,y) = \partial_y f(x+h,y),
$$
so that by the axiom applied to $g(x) = \partial_y f(x,y)$ for fixed $y$,
$$
 \partial_y \partial_x f(x,y) = \partial_x\partial_y f(x,y),
$$
as was claimed.

Comment: ok, understood, the final equality follows by applying two times the unicity condition in the axiom